# python: printing horizontally rather than current default printing

Tags: python

I was wondering if we can print like row-wise in python.

Basically I have a loop which might go on million times and I am printing out some strategic counts in that loop.. so it would be really cool if I can print like row-wise

```
print x
# currently gives
# 3
# 4
#.. and so on
```

and i am looking something like

```
print x
# 3 4
```

Comment: You could always concat `x` and print after the loop completes :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In Python2:

```
data = [3, 4]
for x in data:
    print x,    # notice the comma at the end of the line
```

or in Python3:

```
for x in data:
    print(x, end=' ')
```

prints

```
3 4
```

Comment: The print function support horizontal printing, so using a for loop is the wrong way. My answare explain this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63418899/14039999

Answer (score 10):

Just add a `,` at the end of the item(s) you're printing.

```
print(x,)
# 3 4
```

Or in Python 2:

```
print x,
# 3 4
```

Comment: it doesn't work. This give me `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(1, end=" ")?`

Comment: This example, from 2011, only works in Python2. :)

Comment: print(x,) for current versions.

Answer (score 6):

### You don't need to use a for loop to do that!

```py
mylist = list('abcdefg')
print(*mylist, sep=' ') 
# Output: 
# a b c d e f g
```

Here I'm using the unpack operator for iterators: `*`. At the background the print function is beeing called like this: `print('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', sep=' ')`.

Also if you change the value in `sep` parameter you can customize the way you want to print, for exemple:

```py
print(*mylist, sep='\n') 
# Output: 
# a
# b
# c
# d
# e
# f
# g
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add comma at the end it should work for you.

```
>>> def test():
...    print 1,
...    print 2,
... 
>>> test()
1 2
```

Comment: it doesn't work. This give me `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(1, end=" ")?`

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = ['keyboard', 'mouse', 'led', 'monitor', 'headphones', 'dvd']
for i in xrange(0, len(my_list), 4):
    print '\t'.join(my_list[i:i+4])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=int(input("RangeFinal "))
print("Prime Numbers in the range")
for n in range(2, a):
   p=0
   for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
                break
        else:
           if(p==0):
              print(n,end=' ')
              p=1
```

Answer

```
RangeFinal 19
Prime Numbers in the range
3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for your print

`print(x,end="")`

Answer (score 0):

For python 2:

```
for x in num:
    print x,
```

For python 3:

```
for x in num:
    print(x, end = ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3:

```
l = [3.14, 'string', ('tuple', 'of', 'items')]
print(', '.join(map(repr, l)))
```

Output:

> ```
> 3.14, 'string', ('tuple', 'of', 'items')
> ```