# Print A6 double sided booklet using python and Latex

Tags: python, pdf, printing, latex

I want to print a A6 booklet double sided. Even though this question has been posted a lot on the internet I could not find any suitable solution.
I figure out a way using both Latex and python.
I use this Latex code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[skins,raster]{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster height=\textheight,raster equal skip=0pt,blank,

    graphics pages={8,1,6,3, 2,7,4,5}]
   \tcbincludepdf{a6.pdf}% <-- The A6 document with 8 pages
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

To rearange the page in the right order (a6.pdf being my document to print), and I use this python code :

```
L=[]
for i in range(0,100,8):
    L.append(i+8)
    L.append(i+1)
    L.append(i+6)
    L.append(i+3)
    L.append(' '+str(i+2))
    L.append(i+7)
    L.append(i+4)
    L.append(i+5)
```

to generate the list of pages in the right order (here for 100 pages).

1. How can I get python to print horizontally with coma (8,1,6,3,...)? With this thread [python: printing horizontally rather than current default printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437964/python-printing-horizontally-rather-than-current-default-printing) I can print horizontally but not with comas.
2. Could I use PyPDF2 to rearrange the page and get rid of this latex script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your example exactly what you need, but [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/) can easily read in a PDF and rearrange it for printing.

[Here](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/blob/master/examples/subset_booklets.py) is an example that arranges pages four at a time for binding a book, and [here](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/blob/master/examples/booklet.py) is an example that nests the pages, e.g. for stapling.

There are other examples if you need to rotate pages around, as well.

If all you need to do is to arrange the pages, and not place multiple input pages on a single output page, the simplest place to start might be the [subset](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/blob/master/examples/subset.py) example.  There is a `cat` example as well.

Disclaimer:  I am the primary pdfrw author.